# how does a jar file read its own resource file?

Tags: groovy, jar, gradle

I've searched up and down and have not understood solutions to problems that seem like mine. Maybe I do not understand the problem enough to extrapolate my own solution from others' problems. From what I could find online, it seems like program 1 is trying to read resources from inside a jar. I'm trying to have a jar read its own resources.

use case:
I have a groovy project that contains source files and resource files. From within the groovy project I can read my resource files (located in src/main/resources/locales) via the following snippet

```
def dictionaryFile = new File("${localeDirectory}/${name}/${locale}.json");
```

where localeDirectory = src/main/resources/locales.

I use gradle to build my groovy project into a library to be used with a separate application (application 2). When application 2 starts to use this jar, the above snippet fails to find the resource file. I've looked at the structure of my jar file and see gradle puts the resource under locales (not src/main/resources/locales).

In what way can I have my groovy project access my resource files AND have application2 be able to use the built jar file to access its own resource files as well?

Comment: The way to read resource files on the JVM is ClassLoader#getResource(AsStream). A web search should give plenty of information.

Comment: I was finally able to find a very good example (from start to finish) on how to use the classloader resource stream. Turns out my resources were not being found since it was in a different package than the class requesting the resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
def final InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("${localeDirectory}/${name}/${locale}.json");
```

This worked once I changed my project structure to have the locale directory in the same package as the class that is requesting the resource files.